# Insert ordered data into a table and then get the first row in a group by query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question related to the ordering and grouping of data.

In the query below, I have inserted the order ids, payment ids, public ids and created at dates of some payments, ordered by the order id and the date created:

```
INSERT INTO order_payment_public_id (order_id, payment_id, public_id, created_at)
SELECT o.order_id, p.payment_id, ppid.public_id, p.created_at 
FROM order_ids o 
JOIN payment_request_index pr ON o.order_id=pr.order_id 
JOIN payment_index p ON p.payment_request_id=pr.payment_request_id 
JOIN payment_public_id ppid ON ppid.payment_id=p.payment_id 
ORDER BY o.order_id ASC, p.created_at ASC;
```

I then execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM order_payment_public_id GROUP BY order_id;
```

When I execute the first query, I would expect that the earliest `created_at` date will be in the first row when an `order_id` appears for the first time. Then when I execute the second query I would expect that I will be left with the orders containing the earliest `created_at` dates.

My question is: Are my assumptions correct? When using `GROUP BY order_id`, does the query always group by the first row in which each `order_id` appears, containing the earliest `created_at` date?

I will appreciate any help in regards to my question. Many thanks.

Comment: No, they are not correct. When you make a SELECT with no ORDER BY, the systems returns the information in the order it founds it, and it may not be the same as the order you created. The reason is that when you insert info in a DB, it uses the space it founds free, and maybe it's is not a consecutive space

Comment: I would say that, without a specific selection clause (e.g., `WHERE (order_id IS NOT NULL) OR (order_id <> '')`), your second `SELECT` statement may well return data whether `order_id` is empty or not. Your `INSERT...SELECT` statement doesn't specify that `o.order_id` must contain a value, so your second `SELECT` won't know. If `pr.order_id` is not empty/null, the `JOIN` will pick up that data too. Also, add an `ORDER BY` clause to the second one - MySQL isn't under any obligation to return the data you request sorted by the primary key

Comment: Never use `select *` with `group by`.  This is a (mis)feature in MySQL.  It only causes more confusion than it is worth.  And, the SQL you learn won't work on other databases.